# Find optimal combination of elements from two arrays for a total of five elements

Tags: combinations

I have two arrays `array_a` and `array_b`.
Each array can have anywhere between zero and infinite number of elements, but I need to select just a total of 5 from both.

Optimal combination is 3 from `array_a` and 2 from `array_b`.

If the total in either arrays is less than its optimal number, it should be compensated from the other array (e.g. 4 from `array_a` and 1 from `array_b`) to make up a total of 5.

Given that I know total number of elements in both arrays, what's the most efficient way of calculating the optimal combination?

My pseudo-code solution in Python is the following, but I have a feeling it can be done even more efficiently:

```py
source_a_count = array_a.len()
source_b_count = array_b.len()

if source_a_count =< 3
  source_b_count = 5 - source_a_count
else if source_b_count =< 2
  source_a_count = 5 - source_b_count
else
  source_a_count = 3
  source_b_count = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can reduce if-else statements.

```
source_a_count = 3
source_b_count = 2

if array_a.len() < 3 
  source_a_count = array_a.len()
  source_b_count = 5 - source_a_count
else if array_b.len() < 2
  source_b_count = array_b.len()
  source_a_count = 5 - source_b_count
```

Comment: This is my first time writing an answer and i don't know how to indent it corrrectly. Sorry for that